# How to create a mobile menu using css

Tags: html, css

How to properly create a mobile menu.  I tried like this but it streches the complete header when menu is opened

```js
function openMobileMenu() {
  const x = document.getElementById('mobile-links');
  if (x.style.display === 'block') {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
#searchBtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
}

svg {
   background-color:#333;
}

#logo {
  width: 50px;
}

.lead {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@mixin heder-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  .header-logo {
    flex-basis: 20%;
    svg {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
  .header-search-bar {
    align-self: center;
    flex-basis: 40%;
  }
  .header-categories {
    align-self: center;
    a {
      @include heder-text();
    }
    a:hover {
      border: solid 1px white;
    }
  }
  .header-account-drop-down {
    // position: relative;
    // display: flex;
    // justify-content: space-between;
    ul.drop-menu {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    ul li {
      display: none;
      list-style: none;
    }
    // ul:hover {
    //     color: #000;
    // }
  }
  .dropbtn {
    border: none;
    height: 50px;
    @include heder-text();
  }
  /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  /* Links inside the dropdown */
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }

  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    border: solid 1px white;
  }
  .header-cart {
    align-self: center;
    a {
      @include heder-text();
    }
    a:hover {
      border: solid 1px white;
    }
  }
  .mobile-links {
    display: none;
    a {
      color: white;
    }
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: "480px") {
  .header {
    .header-logo {
      flex-basis: 80%;
    }
    .icon {
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-end;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .mobile-links {
      text-align: end;
      a {
        padding: 14px 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }
  .header-search-bar,
  .header-categories,
  .header-account-drop-down,
  .header-cart {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="header bg-main">

  <div class="header-logo">
    <svg routerLink="/" alt="logo" id="logo" viewBox="0 0 482.0110168457031 91.14653778076172"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class=" logo" id="fdaabegh" style="width: 75%; height: 100%;">
      <defs id="SvgjsDefs1027"></defs>
      <g id="SvgjsG1028" featurekey="root" fill="#2d3440"></g>
      <g id="SvgjsG1029" featurekey="symbol1" fill="#ffffff"
        transform="matrix(0.7905170760421555,0,0,0.7905170760421555,6.067156889944477,6.0474146197892225)">
        <path fill="#fff"
          d="M83.22,28.485c-6.138-9.724-13.995-16.732-23.353-20.827C55.787,5.87,51.33,5,46.244,5  c-0.662,0-1.35,0.015-2.045,0.044c-1.764,0.073-3.669,0.239-5.823,0.509c-3.393,0.424-6.462,1.412-9.122,2.939  c-2.661,1.524-5.046,3.661-7.089,6.351c-2.596,3.416-4.572,7.483-6.042,12.432c-1.777,5.984-2.56,11.88-2.327,17.525  c0.189,4.595,1.057,9.142,2.579,13.515c1.156,3.322,2.756,6.192,4.756,8.53c1.327,1.552,2.862,2.901,4.578,4.024  c-2.11,1.34-4.377,2.373-6.753,3.456c-0.606,0.276-1.215,0.554-1.826,0.839l-0.024,0.011l-0.023,0.013  C4.099,82.13,4.958,90.976,5.001,91.349L5.421,95l1.442-3.38c0.039-0.09,4.084-9.227,15.62-13.272  c7.227-2.534,7.77-2.946,9.145-4.477c0.285-0.317,0.608-0.677,1.093-1.137c2.872-2.713,4.545-6.322,4.972-10.725  c1.941,0.946,3.995,1.425,6.122,1.425c0.198,0,0.397-0.004,0.596-0.013c0.806-0.033,1.626-0.135,2.45-0.305  c0.243,3.508,1.523,6.607,3.717,8.987c2.384,2.596,5.819,4.269,9.931,4.839c4.059,0.566,7.018,1.74,9.395,2.683  c0.322,0.128,0.634,0.251,0.936,0.369c8.487,1.849,7.437,14.528,7.437,14.528l0.28,0.001c0,0,15.083-18.86,14.967-35.277  C93.095,48.83,89.725,38.78,83.22,28.485z M29.858,27.716c0.753-2.336,1.948-4.269,3.551-5.744c1.422-1.304,3.127-2.246,5.19-2.865  c0.188,2.552,1.056,4.873,1.863,6.862c1.694,4.153,4.184,7.882,7.614,11.403c2.37,2.433,5.17,4.743,8.771,7.235  c-0.489,2.21-1.317,4.393-2.412,6.355c-1.398,2.508-3.2,4.688-5.212,6.305c-2.097,1.685-4.321,2.619-6.432,2.703l-0.315,0.006  c-1.214,0-2.352-0.268-3.48-0.819c-1.315-0.646-2.54-1.665-3.64-3.028c-4.417-5.489-6.794-11.401-7.064-17.571  C28.143,35.057,28.669,31.409,29.858,27.716z M52.078,58.259l0.348-1.529c1.429-1.507,2.677-3.249,3.713-5.184  c0.755-1.413,1.378-2.908,1.859-4.458c2.692,1.958,5.533,3.556,8.078,4.987c0.621,0.348,1.234,0.694,1.844,1.041  c2.168,1.396,4.481,2.903,6.72,4.476c0.5,0.351,1.006,0.716,1.511,1.091l0.14,0.119c2.372,2.127,4.03,3.938,5.2,5.683  c1.446,2.159,2.194,4.273,2.287,6.465c0.014,0.366,0.028,0.75-0.011,1.118c-0.419,4.007-2.195,9.047-3.469,12.108  c-0.656-2.07-2.013-4.802-4.813-6.947c-3.467-2.531-8.275-4.234-14.309-5.075c-3.029-0.426-5.398-1.545-7.041-3.325  c-1.527-1.662-2.358-3.825-2.47-6.427C51.611,61.092,51.75,59.697,52.078,58.259z M70.44,48.988  c-4.379-2.822-14.387-10.052-20.278-14.65c-2.349-2.528-4.05-5.184-5.198-8.116c-0.596-1.516-1.156-3.123-1.214-4.621  c-0.006-0.143-0.008-0.282-0.005-0.42c0.003-0.152,0.001-0.302-0.004-0.451c-0.023-0.516-0.094-0.943-0.225-1.351  c-0.127-0.393-0.308-0.748-0.538-1.056c-0.369-0.507-0.931-0.922-1.534-1.128c-0.388-0.137-0.8-0.205-1.25-0.205l-0.189,0.004  c-0.563,0.026-1.033,0.132-1.466,0.239c-2.84,0.708-5.258,2.006-7.189,3.859c-1.911,1.828-3.317,4.169-4.176,6.957  c-1.135,3.675-1.636,7.329-1.489,10.859c0.256,6.278,2.535,12.24,6.776,17.719c0.312,0.404,0.654,0.798,1.034,1.193  c-0.246,0.479-0.334,0.92-0.378,1.219c-0.052,0.362-0.067,0.74-0.05,1.195l0.006,0.12v0.002c-0.004,0.047-0.015,0.117-0.033,0.21  l-0.032,0.165c-0.039,0.199-0.094,0.471-0.127,0.796c-0.173,1.73-0.557,3.205-1.174,4.514c-0.337,0.713-0.739,1.366-1.219,1.98  c-2.235-1.053-4.099-2.469-5.679-4.314c-1.605-1.875-2.905-4.222-3.864-6.976c-1.366-3.926-2.145-8.006-2.315-12.126  c-0.211-5.108,0.506-10.475,2.131-15.951c1.3-4.379,3.019-7.939,5.258-10.884c1.674-2.201,3.52-3.864,5.644-5.082  c2.13-1.22,4.523-1.984,7.315-2.335c2.018-0.253,3.791-0.408,5.421-0.475c0.627-0.026,1.246-0.039,1.839-0.039  c4.463,0,8.177,0.715,11.689,2.251c8.569,3.756,15.505,9.964,21.204,18.98c6.039,9.565,9.166,18.837,9.56,28.345  c0.059,1.398-0.21,4.131-0.506,6.458c-0.893-2.149-2.102-4.424-3.035-5.524c-1.533-1.811-3.428-3.537-5.962-5.43  C76.444,52.523,73.364,50.653,70.44,48.988z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="SvgjsG1030" featurekey="text1" fill="#ffffff"
        transform="matrix(3.31491670788717,0,0,3.31491670788717,96.3535919374592,-16.817670982191686)">
        <path
          d="M10.1 16.56 c0.16 0 0.28 0.12 0.28 0.3 l0 3.08 c0 2.8 -1.46 4.16 -4.02 4.16 l-1.24 0 c-2.56 0 -4.02 -1.36 -4.02 -4.16 l0 -5.88 c0 -2.8 1.46 -4.16 4.02 -4.16 l1.24 0 c2.48 0 3.9 1.26 4.02 3.94 c0 0.18 -0.12 0.28 -0.28 0.28 l-0.44 0 c-0.18 0 -0.3 -0.1 -0.3 -0.28 c-0.08 -2.08 -0.96 -2.98 -3 -2.98 l-1.24 0 c-2.12 0 -3 0.98 -3 3.2 l0 5.88 c0 2.22 0.88 3.2 3 3.2 l1.24 0 c2.14 0 3 -0.98 3 -3.2 l0 -2.44 l-2.26 0 c-0.16 0 -0.28 -0.1 -0.28 -0.28 l0 -0.36 c0 -0.18 0.12 -0.3 0.28 -0.3 l3 0 z M18.240000000000002 14.88 c-0.08 0.18 -0.22 0.2 -0.38 0.14 c-0.28 -0.1 -0.6 -0.16 -1.02 -0.16 l-0.24 0 c-1.66 0 -2.62 1.04 -2.94 1.58 l0 7.26 c0 0.2 -0.1 0.3 -0.3 0.3 l-0.38 0 c-0.2 0 -0.3 -0.1 -0.3 -0.3 l0 -9.4 c0 -0.2 0.1 -0.3 0.3 -0.3 l0.38 0 c0.2 0 0.3 0.1 0.3 0.3 l0 1.26 c0.78 -1.14 1.92 -1.64 3.26 -1.64 c0.44 0 0.9 0.06 1.3 0.16 c0.18 0.08 0.24 0.2 0.18 0.38 z M27.48 23.82 c0.02 0.08 0.04 0.18 -0.06 0.18 l-0.64 0 c-0.22 0 -0.32 -0.2 -0.32 -0.48 l0 -1.2 c-0.62 1.04 -1.56 1.78 -3.02 1.78 l-0.92 0 c-1.8 0 -2.9 -1 -2.9 -2.98 c0 -2 1.14 -2.88 2.86 -2.88 l3.98 0 l0 -0.62 c0 -2.14 -0.52 -2.76 -2.44 -2.76 l-0.38 0 c-1.06 0 -1.78 0.18 -2.48 0.54 c-0.18 0.1 -0.36 0.14 -0.42 -0.02 l-0.22 -0.42 c-0.06 -0.12 -0.04 -0.22 0.16 -0.34 c0.8 -0.52 1.86 -0.7 2.96 -0.7 l0.38 0 c2.48 0 3.42 1.14 3.42 3.68 l0 5.92 c0 0.1 0.02 0.22 0.04 0.3 z M23.36 23.14 c1.62 0 2.68 -0.9 3.1 -2.22 l0 -1.78 l-3.94 0 c-1.24 0 -1.92 0.48 -1.92 1.98 s0.68 2.02 1.92 2.02 l0.84 0 z M34.04 13.92 c2.38 0 3.18 1.2 3.18 3.54 l0 6.24 c0 0.2 -0.1 0.3 -0.3 0.3 l-0.38 0 c-0.2 0 -0.3 -0.1 -0.3 -0.3 l0 -6.18 c0 -1.74 -0.4 -2.66 -2.18 -2.66 l-0.34 0 c-1.66 0 -2.62 1.04 -2.94 1.58 l0 7.26 c0 0.2 -0.1 0.3 -0.3 0.3 l-0.38 0 c-0.2 0 -0.3 -0.1 -0.3 -0.3 l0 -9.4 c0 -0.2 0.1 -0.3 0.3 -0.3 l0.38 0 c0.2 0 0.3 0.1 0.3 0.3 l0 1.26 c0.78 -1.12 1.9 -1.64 3.1 -1.64 l0.16 0 z  M46.980000000000004 10 c0.2 0 0.3 0.1 0.3 0.3 l0 13.4 c0 0.2 -0.1 0.3 -0.3 0.3 l-0.38 0 c-0.2 0 -0.3 -0.1 -0.3 -0.3 l0 -1.22 c-0.42 1 -1.24 1.62 -2.72 1.62 l-0.72 0 c-2.08 0 -3.54 -1.34 -3.54 -3.68 l0 -2.86 c0 -2.38 1.46 -3.64 3.54 -3.64 l0.72 0 c1.48 0 2.3 0.52 2.72 1.5 l0 -5.12 c0 -0.2 0.1 -0.3 0.3 -0.3 l0.38 0 z M43.72 23.14 c1.66 0 2.58 -0.92 2.58 -2.64 l0 -2.88 c0 -1.86 -0.92 -2.76 -2.58 -2.76 l-0.84 0 c-1.66 0 -2.58 0.9 -2.58 2.76 l0 2.88 c0 1.72 0.92 2.64 2.58 2.64 l0.84 0 z  M60.86000000000001 10 c2.44 0 3.9 1.26 3.9 3.98 l0 6.04 c0 2.72 -1.46 3.98 -3.9 3.98 l-4.48 0 l-0.3 0 c-0.2 0 -0.3 -0.1 -0.3 -0.3 l0 -13.4 c0 -0.2 0.1 -0.3 0.3 -0.3 l0.42 0 l4.36 0 z M63.74 20.02 l0 -6.04 c0 -2.14 -0.88 -3.02 -2.88 -3.02 l-4.06 0 l0 12.08 l4.06 0 c2 0 2.88 -0.88 2.88 -3.02 z M70.82 13.92 c1.72 0 3.48 1.28 3.48 3.62 l0 1.26 c0 0.38 -0.26 0.62 -0.66 0.62 l-6.06 0 l0 1.18 c0 1.62 0.92 2.54 2.58 2.54 l0.66 0 c1.4 0 1.78 -0.58 2.4 -1.32 c0.14 -0.16 0.22 -0.2 0.42 -0.06 l0.26 0.18 c0.2 0.14 0.18 0.26 0.06 0.42 c-0.72 0.88 -1.44 1.74 -3.14 1.74 l-0.66 0 c-2.1 0 -3.6 -1.32 -3.6 -3.56 l0 -2.98 c0 -2.38 1.5 -3.64 3.6 -3.64 l0.66 0 z M73.28 18.52 l0 -0.9 c0 -1.86 -1.06 -2.76 -2.46 -2.76 l-0.66 0 c-1.66 0 -2.58 0.9 -2.58 2.74 l0 0.92 l5.7 0 z M79.78 18.48 c2.06 0.26 3.76 0.5 3.76 2.74 c0 2.08 -1.58 2.88 -3.4 2.88 l-0.8 0 c-1.84 0 -3.02 -0.9 -3.32 -2.48 c-0.04 -0.18 0.06 -0.3 0.26 -0.3 l0.5 0 c0.16 0 0.26 0.1 0.28 0.28 c0.26 1.08 0.96 1.54 2.28 1.54 l0.8 0 c1.36 0 2.42 -0.42 2.42 -1.92 s-1.3 -1.66 -2.78 -1.84 c-2.16 -0.24 -3.6 -0.6 -3.6 -2.78 c0 -1.9 1.28 -2.66 3.26 -2.66 l0.58 0 c1.86 0 3.12 0.84 3.2 2.66 c0 0.2 -0.06 0.32 -0.28 0.32 l-0.44 0 c-0.18 0 -0.3 -0.12 -0.3 -0.32 c-0.1 -1.2 -0.84 -1.76 -2.22 -1.76 l-0.5 0 c-1.44 0 -2.32 0.42 -2.32 1.78 c0 1.44 1.04 1.68 2.62 1.86 z M85.78 10.3 c0 -0.2 0.1 -0.3 0.3 -0.3 l0.32 0 c0.2 0 0.3 0.1 0.3 0.3 l0 0.44 c0 0.2 -0.1 0.3 -0.3 0.3 l-0.32 0 c-0.2 0 -0.3 -0.1 -0.3 -0.3 l0 -0.44 z M85.74000000000001 14.3 c0 -0.2 0.1 -0.3 0.3 -0.3 l0.38 0 c0.2 0 0.3 0.1 0.3 0.3 l0 9.4 c0 0.2 -0.1 0.3 -0.3 0.3 l-0.38 0 c-0.2 0 -0.3 -0.1 -0.3 -0.3 l0 -9.4 z M96.68 14 c0.2 0 0.3 0.1 0.3 0.3 l0 10.28 c0 2.3 -1.42 3.42 -4.14 3.42 c-0.64 0 -1.12 -0.02 -1.78 -0.18 c-0.12 -0.02 -0.18 -0.08 -0.18 -0.18 l0 -0.6 c0 -0.12 0.06 -0.18 0.18 -0.16 c0.66 0.16 1.14 0.18 1.78 0.18 c1.94 0 3.16 -0.42 3.16 -2.44 l0 -2.14 c-0.42 1 -1.24 1.62 -2.72 1.62 l-0.72 0 c-2.08 0 -3.54 -1.34 -3.54 -3.68 l0 -2.86 c0 -2.38 1.46 -3.64 3.54 -3.64 l0.72 0 c1.48 0 2.3 0.52 2.72 1.5 l0 -1.12 c0 -0.2 0.1 -0.3 0.3 -0.3 l0.38 0 z M93.42 23.14 c1.66 0 2.58 -0.92 2.58 -2.64 l0 -2.88 c0 -1.86 -0.92 -2.76 -2.58 -2.76 l-0.84 0 c-1.66 0 -2.58 0.9 -2.58 2.76 l0 2.88 c0 1.72 0.92 2.64 2.58 2.64 l0.84 0 z M103.62 13.92 c2.38 0 3.18 1.2 3.18 3.54 l0 6.24 c0 0.2 -0.1 0.3 -0.3 0.3 l-0.38 0 c-0.2 0 -0.3 -0.1 -0.3 -0.3 l0 -6.18 c0 -1.74 -0.4 -2.66 -2.18 -2.66 l-0.34 0 c-1.66 0 -2.62 1.04 -2.94 1.58 l0 7.26 c0 0.2 -0.1 0.3 -0.3 0.3 l-0.38 0 c-0.2 0 -0.3 -0.1 -0.3 -0.3 l0 -9.4 c0 -0.2 0.1 -0.3 0.3 -0.3 l0.38 0 c0.2 0 0.3 0.1 0.3 0.3 l0 1.26 c0.78 -1.12 1.9 -1.64 3.1 -1.64 l0.16 0 z  M112.58 18.48 c2.06 0.26 3.76 0.5 3.76 2.74 c0 2.08 -1.58 2.88 -3.4 2.88 l-0.8 0 c-1.84 0 -3.02 -0.9 -3.32 -2.48 c-0.04 -0.18 0.06 -0.3 0.26 -0.3 l0.5 0 c0.16 0 0.26 0.1 0.28 0.28 c0.26 1.08 0.96 1.54 2.28 1.54 l0.8 0 c1.36 0 2.42 -0.42 2.42 -1.92 s-1.3 -1.66 -2.78 -1.84 c-2.16 -0.24 -3.6 -0.6 -3.6 -2.78 c0 -1.9 1.28 -2.66 3.26 -2.66 l0.58 0 c1.86 0 3.12 0.84 3.2 2.66 c0 0.2 -0.06 0.32 -0.28 0.32 l-0.44 0 c-0.18 0 -0.3 -0.12 -0.3 -0.32 c-0.1 -1.2 -0.84 -1.76 -2.22 -1.76 l-0.5 0 c-1.44 0 -2.32 0.42 -2.32 1.78 c0 1.44 1.04 1.68 2.62 1.86 z">
        </path>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="openMobileMenu()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>

    <div class="mobile-links" id='mobile-links'>
      <a class="header-search-bar">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control">
          <span id="searchBtn" class="bg-warning">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
              </span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="nav-link">Categories</a>
      <a class="nav-link">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart mr-1"></i>Cart
        <span class="badge badge-warning ml-1"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your menu element is inside your header element, so showing and hiding the menu within the header means the containing header has to accommodate.
If you want the menu to be separate write the HTML so that the menu is outside of the header element.

Maybe

```
<header>
  <div class="bg-main">This is the title bar</div>
  <nav id="menu">This is the menu of links</nav>
</header>
```